# Script error when run as cronjob

Tags: python, cron

I have setup a cronjob as below, the script runs perfectly fine when I run it from the shell but when running via cronjob I run into below error.

Any idea what a cronjob does? Any environment issue here? Any pointers to debug?

```
28 21,0 * * * /usr/bin/python /local/mnt/workspace/user/Automation/script.py project branch
```

#### The error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/local/mnt/workspace/user/Automation/script.py", line 74, in <module>
        output = phCmdoutput(phCmd)
      File "/local/mnt/workspace/user/Automation/script.py", line 28, in phCmdoutput
        phPipe = Popen(phCmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `phCmd` in sentence `phPipe = Popen(phCmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)` is using relative pathname for some file or the program itself. You could check about it, and change them to absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are environment issues - you don't have the same environment!  `$PATH`, for example, might well be different.

Most likely cause is `phCmd` contains the name of a program by a relative pathname rather than an absolute one.  General rule when running programs through `cron` is to use fully qualified absolute pathnames for everything.